# NaiveBayes Classifer in R predicting only one Class

Tags: r, classification, text-classification, naivebayes

I am working on classifying arduino posts into hardware and software categories. I have manually prepared the train set. 
But, while entering the test set, all posts are predicted as "hardware".
Is there some mistake in the train set format. Does NaiveBayes fail to identify sentences as input to perform prediction?
The train-set format is: class "\t" pred "\t" set
The classifier will take set column to identify labels and pred column as the predicator. Class column is used only to create set column.

```
//programmed in R
library(e1071)
train = read.table("train_set.csv", sep="\t", header=T)
test = read.table("test_one.csv", sep="\t", header=T)
train$set = "Hardware"
train[train$class==0,]$set = "Software"
train$set = as.factor(train$set)
model <- naiveBayes(set ~ pred, data = train)
pred <- predict(model, train[495:510,]) //displays train set prediction
pred1 <- predict(model, test[1:10,]) //displays incorrect prediction for test set
```

Train data set (delimiter = \t, attaching only 4 rows of 1000 rows )

1 represents hardware
0 represents software
In the program, another column called "set" is appended to store "hardware" or "software" corresponding to 1 and 0.

```
class   pred
1    Im making a simple Arduino web server and I want to keep it turned on all the time. So it must endure to stay working continuously. Im using an Arduino Uno with a Ethernet Shield.Its powered with a simple outlet power supply 5V @ 1A. My Questions: Will I have any problems leaving the Arduino turned on all the time? Is there some other Arduino board better recommended for this? Are there any precautions that I need to heed regarding this? 
1    Put plainly: is there a way to get an HTTPS connection on the Arduino? I have been looking in to it and I have found it is impossible with the standard library and the Ethernet shield but is there a custom library that can do it? What about a coprocessor i.e. like the WiFi shield has? Anyone know if the Arduino yn has ssl? 
0    The use of malloc and free seems pretty rare in the Arduino world. It is used in pure AVR C much more often but still with caution. Is it a really bad idea to use malloc and free with Arduino? 
0    What do I need to build a shield capable of receiving 1080p video from USB camera timestamp each frame and send the frame to memory card?
```

Test data set

```
 pred
arduino-uno web-server ethernet i'm making a simple arduino web server and i want to keep it turned on all the time. so it must endure to stay working continuously. i'm using an arduino uno with a ethernet shield.it's powered with a simple outlet power supply 5v @ 1a. my questions: will i have any problems leaving the arduino turned on all the time? is there some other arduino board better recommended for this? are there any precautions that i need to heed regarding this?    
I made a circuit which in my intentions would allow me to toggle a LED dimming loop. Problem is that once I push the button the first time pushing it a second time doesnt toggle the LED loop off. Here is the code: const int LED = 9; // the pin for the LEDconst int BUTTON = 7;int val = LOW;int old_val = LOW;int state = 0;int i = 0;void setup{ pinModeLED OUTPUT; pinModeBUTTON INPUT;}void loop{ val = digitalReadBUTTON; if val == HIGH &amp;&amp; old_val==LOW { state = 1 - state; delay10; } old_val = val; if state == 1 { for i = 0; i &lt; 255; i++ // loop from 0 to 254 fade in { analogWriteLED i; // set the LED brightness delay10; // Wait 10ms because analogWrite // is instantaneous and we would // not see any change } for i = 255; i &gt; 0; i-- // loop from 255 to 1 fade out { analogWriteLED i; // set the LED brightness delay10; // Wait 10m
```

Expected Output:
Hardware Software

Comment: Ummmm...where is your document-term matrix? What is `head(train)` (if it is the snippet you posted, then you are missing one very crucial step)

Comment: I am missing the document-term matrix. Thanks for mentioning it. I will post the document-term matrix asap. I am very new to this field. 
I can use tf-idf weighing measure for document-term matrix.
@Vlo

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vlo Your one question on document-term matrix guided me to the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(e1071)
library(tm)
library(MASS)
library(SnowballC)

train = read.table("train_set.csv", sep="\t", header=T)
test = read.table("test_set.csv", sep="\t", header=T)

#stopwords
mystopwords <- c(stopwords("english"),"week","arduino","words","need","get","will","want","know","work","also")

#corpus for train set
train.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(train$pred))
train.corpus <- tm_map(train.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
train.corpus <- tm_map(train.corpus, removePunctuation)
train.corpus <- tm_map(train.corpus, stripWhitespace)
train.corpus <- tm_map(train.corpus, removeNumbers)
train.corpus <- tm_map(train.corpus, removeWords, mystopwords)
train.corpus <- tm_map(train.corpus, stemDocument)
train.corpus <- tm_map(train.corpus, removeWords, "(http)\\w+")
train.corpus <- tm_map(train.corpus, removeWords, "\\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,100}\\b")
train.corpus.dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(train.corpus, control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE), stopwords = TRUE, removePunctuation=TRUE))
train.corpus.dtms <- removeSparseTerms(train.corpus.dtm, 0.98)

#Debugging
#TermDocumentMatrix(train.corpus)
#inspect(train.corpus.dtm)
#findFreqTerms(train.corpus.dtm, N)   #N <- freq

#corpus for test set
test.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(test$pred))
test.corpus <- tm_map(test.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
test.corpus <- tm_map(test.corpus, removePunctuation)
test.corpus <- tm_map(test.corpus, stripWhitespace)
test.corpus <- tm_map(test.corpus, removeNumbers)
test.corpus <- tm_map(test.corpus, removeWords, mystopwords)
test.corpus <- tm_map(test.corpus, stemDocument)
test.corpus <- tm_map(test.corpus, removeWords, "(http)\\w+")
test.corpus <- tm_map(test.corpus, removeWords, "\\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,100}\\b")
test.corpus.dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(test.corpus, control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE), stopwords = TRUE, removePunctuation=TRUE))
test.corpus.dtms <- removeSparseTerms(test.corpus.dtm, 0.98) 


m <- as.matrix(train.corpus.dtms)
n <- as.matrix(test.corpus.dtms)

#Train model
model <- naiveBayes(m,as.factor(train$class));

#Prediction
results <- predict(model,n[1:10,])
```

The next step is to include 10-fold cross validation into this classifier for performance check; where I am stuck right now.

Comment: You can use `library(caret)` with the naivebayes implementation in `library(klaR)` http://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html

Comment: doesn't 'caret' work on R 3.1.2? Its dependent on 'car' which works on >= 3.2. 
R 3.2 have incompatibility issues with some packages for which I downgraded to R 3.1  
Any suggestions.

Comment: Create your own test and training datasets. It is not difficult.

Comment: I have processed the data-set of arduino.stackexchange.com dump as per my requirement. The traininng and test data sets are refined my me. And how is creating own datasets relevant to this query?

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you resolve that naive beyes predicts only one class?

Comment: @KHANirfan My problem was related to DocumentTerm Matrix. I was directly giving Strings as input into the model which is incorrect. First step is to create DocumentTerm Matrix which is nothing but vectorization of the String and some basic normalisations.